# Can I use glob to filter an existing list of file paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm using glob for some file searching operations in Node, and also using glob patterns for an "ignore" list.

But I also want to be able to use *just* the ignore list, to filter an existing list of files (in this case changed files from git). Is there a way to use the glob library just as a text filter, rather than needing to interact with the filesystem? I don't want to have two separate implementations of the pattern depending on use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the code for Glob, looks like the answer is in [minimatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) which glob uses for comparing paths.